# How do I install bcrypt using npm?

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, sha256, ubuntu-20.04

I have nodejs version 10.19.0, ubuntu 20.04.2, and use webstorm ide for javascript.  I tried installing both bcrypt and sha256 and neither libraries worked.
For example, after installing bcrypt the first 2 lines in my javascript code is:

```
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    alert('hello');
```

The alert function only pops up when I comment out the first line.  I have the same problem with sha256.

I have tried installing, uninstalling, and reinstalling bcrypt and bcryptjs (even the bcrypt version that was supposed to match my node version).  Why can't I seem to get these libraries to install properly?  Thanks.

PS.  I tried 'npm install bcrypt'

```
    $ npm list -g
    (node:40710) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is 
    experimental
    /home/philip/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib
    ├── bcrypt@5.0.1
    ├── create-react-app@3.3.1
    ├── node-gyp@8.1.0
    ├── npm@7.16.0
    └── truffle@5.1.39
```

Comment: ` const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');  alert('hello'); ` is this code present in your HTML file? because alert is used as window alert in HTML files and the way you have used bcrypt is syntax for backend like app.js

Comment: Not directly.   <script type="application/javascript" src="js/todo.js"></script> at the end of the body.  Should I try console.log instead?

Comment: if you have used `npm install bcrypt` then you need to use bcrypt in backend, check this example https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/hashing-user-passwords-using-bcryptjs/ or refer their npm website https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://browserify.org/ is the only solution I tried that worked.  Thank you everyone for your help.

Edit:  I no longer need to use browserify to use bcrypt in my javascript application!

Here are the changes I did to make it work:

In todoApp.html...

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/todo.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Todo App</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bcryptjs@2.4.3/dist/bcrypt.js"></script>
 </head>

...

     <script src="scripts/todo.js"></script>
 </body>
```

In todo.js

```
let bcrypt = dcodeIO.bcrypt;
const saltRounds = 12;
...
```

Comment: also try this library based on bcrypt but really easy to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-inzi

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should properly look into how to install bcrypt in your project, You can look into this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt for detailed installation and you would also be able to get further help from it. But right now the problem is that you are not importing bcrypt properly in your js file. You should import it like this and it will work fine.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
```

Comment: OP uses `npm iinstall bcrypt` and if you refer bcrypt npm package this is not the correct way.

Comment: I tried  'npm install -g browserify' but that didn't work either.  I found this error message after looking at chrome's console log:  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at todo.js:1

Comment: @PhilipStephens require is not meant for html files it sis meant for backend node js files. refer the example i posted in my comment.

Comment: @Jatin I tried  " import bcrypt from 'bcryptj; "   and  "  import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'; "  but neither of them worked.  Is there a short snippet that illustrates how to use bcrypt in javascript because I want to use it on a web application and not the backend?

Comment: I tested 'bcryptjs' here: https://runkit.com/embed/lsr3gv9wpxj8 .  It works except I can't get the compare and verify function to return values.  Global variables don't work, neither do the return values but if I console.log the middle of the hash functions it works.  The original comments told me to store the results in a database but I am not using a database.

Comment: This is much simpler and it works.  If only I could get it to work in the browser...
https://runkit.com/embed/zxlgjra2gfe7